# Differences in edit mode preview and final result

Tags: support, editor

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229592/implement-comparator-for-primitive-boolean-type), and wanted to edit and fix the formatting for the `B`, and noticed there's a difference between the live preview and the final result.

**Final result:**

[image]

**Edit mode:**

[image]

---

**Update:** The post was edited so the generated output will be renewed, and now it looks as it's supposed to be.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is something wrong storing this in the DB since the live preview is correct

Comment: I feel so tempted to fix it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yep, I also thought that it's something like that - so it's actually stored "wrong" because the question was written before intra-word emphasis worked (as balpha said in his answer)

Comment: @Cœur Me too! But I don't have 6 characters to change in order to edit ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @arieljannai This is not a problem for 2k rep users. I made the edit, considering you made this screenshot for posterity.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That question was written in 2012, and hasn't been edited since. Intra-word emphasis has only been working [since 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works). Because the Markdown is converted to its rendered version only once (and the rendered version is then stored), you're seeing the question as it was rendered by the Markdown converter in 2012. If someone edited the post now, causing a new rendering, the B would be bold. You can see this in the revision view, which is rendered on demand and doesn't use the stored HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13229592/revisions.

Comment: Oh! Now I know how it works! - Thanks for the information